# How to convert array of objects to object with index?

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

I have a array like this->

```
var jsonResponse = [
     {   
        "name": "abc",
        "value": [
            { "label" : "Daily", "value":"Daily"}         
        ]
    },
    {   
        "name": "ccc",
        "value": [
            { "label" : "Daily", "value":"Daily"}         
        ]
    }
]
```

And I want to convert it to ->

```
{
    "abc" : {   
        "name": "abc",
        "value": [
            { "label" : "Daily", "value":"Daily"}         
        ]
    },
    "ccc": {   
        "name": "ccc",
        "value": [
            { "label" : "Daily", "value":"Daily"}         
        ]
    }
]
```

Probably I dont want foreach.
We can do partial with Object.assign( arrayDetails, ...jsonResponse);
But how to do object index?

Answer (score 1):

```
let indexedResult = {};
jsonResponse.map(obj => indexedResult[obj.name] = obj)

console.log(JSON.stringify(indexedResult));
```